# How to restart this

Tags: python

I am making number guesser program and I am trying to figure out how to restart this if you get the number wrong. I have tried while true loops and It just keeps asking the question. I need some help with this thanks (python). EDIT: j1-lee answered question very good!

```py
import random

ask = input("Guess a number between 0 and 10")

r1 = random.randint(0, 1)
print("The number is % s" %(r1))

if int(ask) == r1:
    print("right")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Comment: Hello...doesn't restart mean asking the guess again?...I guess you should set  fixed number of attempts; use the while loop until a flag is true; set the flag=false if guess is correct or number of attempts are exceeded. keep increasing the attempt count by 1 in each iteration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while True` approach was right. You only need to add `break` at an appropriate place:

```py
import random

while True:
    ask = input("Guess a number between 0 and 10: ")
    r1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    print(f"The correct number is {r1}.")

    if int(ask) == r1:
        print("... and you were right!")
        break
    else:
        print("Try again!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop and set a break when user is correct. Also, change you random generator range, you'll only get 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

if you want the user keep guessing till they find the correct answer, try this:

```py
import random

r1 = random.randint(0, 11)
# print("The number is % s" %(r1))

while True:
    ask = input("Guess a number between 0 and 10: ")
    if int(ask) < 0 or int(ask) > 10:
        print('number you picked is not between 0 and 10')
    else:
        if int(ask) == r1:
            print("correct!")
            break
        else:
            print("try again")
```